# Circuit help for dual-role pushbutton

Tags: battery-operated, analog-switch

I would like to have a pushbutton play two roles:

1. Power up my system by connecting battery power to the EN pin on a boost converter, which then powers an MCU
2. Act as an input for the MCU when the system is powered up.

I was originally thinking of something more complicated than shown below, but I think that an inexpensive dual SPDT analog switch controlled by the MCU might be the easiest option. Hopefully the diagram is self-explanatory. I am wondering if you see any problems with this as shown? Are there precautions that I should take other than the diode shown on the battery line? The diode is to prevent backfeeding the battery when the button is pressed, GPIO1 is driven high, and the lines are not yet swapped. I suppose a current-limiting resistor on GPIO1 would be okay instead (battery voltage is always lower than Vcc)

[image: Dual-role pushbutton]

Comment: I see now that GPIO1 would also need protection to prevent backfeeding from the battery when the system is off and the button is pressed. Is a single diode adequate for that?

Comment: I also realize now that when the analog switch is powered down, all connections are broken (is that correct)? I misunderstood the NO/NC description. Is there an easy alternative, or other suggestions for how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, you have 2 GPIO and one enable pin and a single pole switch.

maybe do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRFyRA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

GPIO 1 can turn the supply on  or off and GPIO2 can sense button ptresses.

choose Zener D2 to limit the signal voltage to something apropriate

But that only works if the supply volage is above the logic voltage.

Now that I know the battery is 1 to 1.5V and the logic is 3.3v the follwing might work better.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcF9dp.png)</sup>

Here the switch turns on the PNP trasnsistor to enable the boost converter

GPIO1 can be used with internal pull-up to sense the buttonn and GPIO2 can be used to command the boost converter. The two diodes should be schottky diodes, the transistor can be any small PNP

Comment: Thanks! That’s simpler than I expected. Please forgive my ignorance, but here are a few questions—I assume both GPIO pins would also need protection from the battery voltage when the button is pressed before the MCU is powered up, correct (additional diodes?)? When you say to choose the Zener to bring the signal to an appropriate level, is that if the battery voltage is higher than the MCU voltage? My battery voltage will 1.5 V or less and the MCU is at 3.0 V, so that won’t be an issue…

Comment: … To add one more level of complexity, there could also be a case where the battery is dead and the MCU is powered by USB, in which case GPIO2 couldn’t sense a button press. However, I assume I could also connect GPIO1 to the left side of the button and protect the battery from back feeding with yet another diode (?).

Comment: I was assuming that battery voltage was above CPU voltage,  the other way round ruins all my plans.

Comment: looking at my second circuit it should work fine with a second supply on Vdd, the boost converter will have a diode that prevents if from accepting current into the output.

Comment: That second one looks great to me. My only remaining question is about protection for the GPIO: Would GPIO2 need a diode as well because it will be subjected to voltage from the battery shortly before the supply turns on? Are Schottkys adequate protection for those two pins?

Comment: the problem with a diode there is you'll lose the capabiltiy tp command the boost rewulator off while the button is pressed.   also I don't think there will be enough voltage from the battery to cause any problems.

Comment: I’m not quite sure I follow—are you saying that EN wouldn’t be pulled low when the button is pressed and GPIO goes low? I had assumed I would also need a pull down on EN to keep it low when the device is shutdown. In that case it would go low as long as GPIO2 isn’t high, correct? I’m a little worried about the GPIO because they are only rated for 0.3V when VCC is 0V.

Comment: button press tries to pull EN high, but the CPU can pull it low if the CPU pulls harder than the 1K resistor.  eg when running off USB power...  only rated for 0.3V - add a shottky diode from GPIO to VCC

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I don't need to worry about commanding EN low when the button is pressed, only when it's not pressed (when it's pressed the system would only power right back up again, correct?). In that case It seems like I could have a weak pulldown on EN and a diode on GPIO2 (?). If I understand correctly, a Schottky clamping GPIO2 to VCC would prevent EN from reaching higher than the forward voltage of the diode when the system is shut down, wouldn't it? I've taken too much of your time, so once I've made a clean schematic I'll present it as a new question for review. Thanks!

Comment: what about USB power the the boost converter turned off?

Comment: Oh, I see. It may be okay if the converter is enabled but backfed with 5V, so I might not have to be able to command EN low? Is there another way to protect GPIO2, though? I don’t understand how a Schottky from it to VCC would work.